# an equivalent condition for a function to be convex

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

[image]

This is a proposition I want to prove. For (a) I think I have to use induction, but the proof seems much more nontrivial than I thought; I cannot find a way to use the induction... Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n t_k z_k = (1-t_n)( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{t_k}{1-t_n} z_k) + t_n z_n$$
Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{t_k}{1-t_n} = 1$.